# Get point-to type of boost shared_ptr

Tags: c++, boost, shared-ptr, smart-pointers

In my project, I use boost::shared_ptr, in one header file, I wrote:

```
typedef boost::shared_ptr<boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<PacketsInput, boost::lockfree::capacity<4096> > > queue_ptr;
```

In another source file, I use it:

```
std::vector<queue_ptr> v;
for (...)
    v.push_back(boost::make_shared(/* #1 */));
```

In #1, I want to write queue_ptr's point to type, rather

```
boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<PacketsInput, boost::lockfree::capacity<4096> >
```

how long it is!

But there is no typedef in boost::shared_ptr, the only one I found is a typedef: `typedef typename boost::detail::sp_element< T >::type element_type;` But I don't know how to use it.

Any help? Tanks a lot!

Comment: If you're using C++11, then you ought to migrate to std::shared_ptr

Comment: @Bathsheba Yes, but my compiler is a bit old, not all c++11 features are supported, I don't want to mix std and boost components ;-)

Comment: _"But there is no typedef in boost::shared_ptr, the only one I found is a typedef"_ so there is one then, and it's exactly what you're looking for!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.htm#Members) says there's a member typedef called `element_type`:

This example program runs fine (assertion passes):

```
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits.hpp>
#include <cassert>

int main()
{
    bool b =  boost::is_same<boost::shared_ptr<int>::element_type, int>::value;
    assert(b);
}
```

Given the typedef you've already declared, you can use it like this:

```
typedef queue_ptr::element_type elem_type;
v.push_back( boost::make_shared<elem_type>( /* args for ctor */ ) );
```

Comment: Thanks, your suggestion is right and a lot help, but use twice make_shard is not compiled, maybe use this v.push_back(boost::make_shared<elem_type>());   ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use two typedefs

```
   typedef boost::lockfree::spsc_queue<PacketsInput, boost::lockfree::capacity<4096> > my_queue;
   typedef boost::shared_ptr<my_queue> my_queue_ptr;
```

And then you can use `my_queue` in `make_shared`.